# Inequality involving a sequence in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

Let $H = L^2(0,T;V)$ where $V$ is separable in $H$. We have $y_n(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_{i,n}(t)b_i$ where $b_i$ are basis vectors in $V$. Suppose we have the estimate
$$\lVert y_n \rVert_H^2 = \int_0^T \lVert y_n(t) \rVert^2_{V} \leq C\left(\lVert y_0 \rVert^2_H + \int_0^T \lVert f(t) \rVert^2_{V^*}\right)$$
for all $n$.
Suppose also
$y_n \rightharpoonup y$ in $H$.

How do I show that 
$$\lVert y \rVert_{H}^2 = \int_0^T \lVert y(t) \rVert^2_{V} \leq C\left(\lVert y_0 \rVert^2_H + \int_0^T \lVert f(t) \rVert^2_{V^*}\right)$$
also holds?

Comment: weak lower semicontinuity of norm will not give you the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equality is the definition of the norm in $H$. For the inequality, we have the following result:

> Let $H$ a Hilbert space, $\{x_n\}$ a sequence which converges weakly to $x$. Then $$\lVert x\rVert\leqslant \liminf_{n\to +\infty}\lVert x_n\rVert.$$

**Proof:** Since $|\langle x,x_n\rangle|\leqslant \lVert x_n\rVert\cdot\lVert x\rVert$, we get 
$$\lVert x\rVert^2=\liminf_{n\to +\infty}|\langle x,x_n\rangle|\leqslant \liminf_{n\to +\infty}\lVert x_n\rVert\cdot\lVert x\rVert.$$
This gives the result (if $x=0$, it's obvious, otherwise divide by $\lVert x\rVert$).

Comment: Note that it also holds when $H$ is a normed space.